# NO_GPGS Does not work on Unity IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, xcode9.1

I am using same project for Android and iOS platforms. In Android, I have used Google Play services but in iOS I don't want to use that. So I add NO_GPGS under Scripting Define Symbols.

[image]

Before this kind of flag was working but now its started showing me error.
I was getting this kind of error in xCode so I can't able to compile it.

[image]

I am using this software versions
Unity 2017.1.2
xCode 9.1

Basically I don't want to compile or use Google Play Services within my iOS project. So I am finding some way to achieve this. Upto now above flag was worked but today not.

Same error other person face at here:
[NO_GPGS Does not work on Unity IOS](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2027)

So please give some solution regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This change worked for me. For both GPG files exist in iOS folder change their **Platform** to **Android** only. Then after it will not create any barrier in xCode project compilation.
Here is reference image for more clearance of others:

[image]

So two steps to perform:

1. NO_GPGS flag in scripting defined symbols and
2. Un-tick iOS platform for GPG files exist in Plugin->iOS folder.